# Corrupted Fonts

Tags: 14.04, gnome, fonts, gtk, lts

I just installed 14.04.2 and certain glyphs are corrupted in Firefox.  It only happens at certain zoom levels.  If I use `Ctrl-mouse-wheel` to zoom the page I can make the corruption appear and disappear.  It appears to be a GTK/GNOME issue.  I see the issue in `Firefox` but not in `Chromium`.

Here's a corrupted example:

[image: Corrupted]

and uncorrupted at a different zoom level

[image: Uncorrupted].

Comment: Good question,  I also noticed similar behavior in LibreOffice, where changing zoom level would change the font style or the font  glyph itself.

Comment: Is this a radeon card? I'm having the same issue, and I just found http://zeroset.mnim.org/2013/01/07/gnome-shell-missing-characters-and-display-corruption-with-xorg-and-radeon/
I'll try, and see if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, it's a Radeon card. I'll check out that link when I'm back in the office tomorrow.

Comment: @StephenRasku Does this problem still occur?

Comment: I don’t have that machine any more. I guess I would say it’s no longer relevant to me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a work around would be key strokes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>+</kbd> to zoom, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>-</kbd> to shrink and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>0</kbd> to return to normal. At least you would know if it was/is a mouse function or error. Seems to work in all browsers I use.